# Extracting non-contiguous array indices from Scala Array into new Array

Tags: arrays, scala

Consider the following Scala Array `x` definition

```
scala> val x = Array(10, 32, 45, 54, 44, 37)
x: Array[Int] = Array(10, 32, 45, 54, 44, 37)
```

and an index `selector`, which is provided, and is guaranteed not to include out of bounds index values:

```
scala> val selector = Seq(0, 3, 5)
selector: Seq[Int] = List(0, 3, 5)
```

In Scala, what is a concise way to use `selector` in combination with `x` to select only those indices of `x` which match the desired indices in `selector` to produce a new `result` Array? Specifically, `result` is expected as:

```
result: Array(10, 54, 37)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event shorter :)

```
 import scala.collection.breakOut
 val result: Array[Int]= selector.map(x)(breakOut)
```

`.map` takes a parameter of type `Function1[Int,_]`, and when we pass `x` there, the compiler is smart enough to figure out, that what me mean is `x.apply`, which is a method `Int => Int`, and it uses *eta-expansion* to convert it into a function, so that we don't have to spell it out explicitly, creating an anonymous function like `.map { idx => x(idx) }`.

`breakOut` is a collection factory, that tells `.map` to return the result as `Array` rather than `List` (because the expected return type on the LHS is `Array`). This avoids building an intermediate collection and then copying it into an array in (`.map(x).toArray`)

Comment: I had no idea about `breakOut`. Short, simple, and I learned something new today. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Access `x` with each `selector` using map.

```
scala> selectors.map(s => x(s)).toArray
res1: Array[Int] = Array(10, 54, 37)
```